# Sending binary data

Tags: c, sockets, binary

Is there any problem doing a loop of `send()` where "`const void *buf`" (2nd argument) is a file descriptor of a file opened as binary mode (`fopen("C:\example.mp3", "rb")`)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to send the contents of the file over the socket? If so, there should be no problem, but you have to read the data from the file into a buffer, then transmit the data in the buffer to the socket.

Answer (score 5):

Argument of `send` must point to memory buffer, filled with values (bytes) you want to send. You can treat the argument `const void *buf` of send() as `const char *buf` - it is just array of chars, which will be not changed by send() function.

But, `fopen()` returns to you a `FILE*` - it is a pointer to special struct `FILE`. So, if you want to send the contents of the file, you should read the contents to `tmp` buffer using `fread()` function & `FILE*` pointer, and then fed the `tmp` buffer to `send()` function. Repeat this code with `fread()` & `send()` until you will reach a end-of-file.

Sample code (found at http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?pid=28854 )

```
int file2socket (FILE *fp, int sockfd)
{
    char tmp[8*1024];
    int len;
    int ret;

    for (ret = 0;;) {
        len = fread (tmp, 1, sizeof (tmp), fp);
        if (len == 0) {
            ret = feof (fp);
            break;
        }
        if (!send (sockfd, tmp, len, 0)) break;
    }

    return (ret);
}
```

Comment: On Linux, there is also a system call `sendfile` which actually eliminates user space and speeds things a lot - http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendfile.2.html

Comment: I would check the return value of `send`.  It might return some value less than `len`, at which case you would want to retry with `tmp + r, len - r` where `r` is the number of bytes sent previously.

Comment: On Linux, there is a system call `splice` that obsoleted `sendfile`.

Comment: @user611775, I checked the splice syscall. Its man don't mark its as obsoleted. Also, glibc will translate it correctly and most users don't do a syscall directly (but I do), rather they use a glibc.